# Ajax ActionLink Blank Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I try to open my data in blank new tab page.However my below code does not open in blank page.

So where i miss ?

```
Ajax.ActionLink("Show","Customer",
new { MusteriId = DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "CustomerId") },
new AjaxOptions
{
//UpdateTargetId = "Customer",
HttpMethod = "POST",
}, new { target = "_blank" }));
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`Ajax.ActionLink` makes an AJAX request to the server and prevents any default actions on the link such as opening it in a new tab. You could use an `Html.ActionLink` if you want the `target="_blank"` attribute to have some effect.

Alternatively you could use some client side library to display the result in a modal dialog such as the [`jQuery UI dialog`](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) widget.